# Any existing workflow on Terra that can run multinomial logistic regression?

Tags: logistic-regression

I need to run multinomial logistic regression on a smaller set of variants e.g. using Trinculo. May I know if there's any existing workflow on Terra that can do this? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

What I think is occurring is Terra is the [Broad Institute's cloud service](https://www.broadinstitute.org/videos/access-data-run-analysis-tools-and-collaborate-cloud-terra). Within that there is a Jupiter notebook and you then just use scikit-learn's (Python) [LogisticRegression()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) using multinomial option. Then is simply ....

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pandas as pd
model = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='lbfgs')
df = pd.DataFrame ({'colA':[1,2,3], 'colB':[1,2,5] ... etc ...)
X = df[['colA', 'colB', 'colC']]
y = df[['colD']]
model.fit(X, y)
preds = model.predict(X) 
print (preds)
```

This sort of operation. Does that make sense?